# How to change directory while using the sub process module

Tags: python

I am using Ubuntu and I am running a command using the subprocess module. I am trying to find the maximum number of days a password can be use.

```
import subprocess

pass_max = subprocess.check_output('grep PASS_MAX_DAYS /etc/login.defs')
print(pass_max)
```

After running this code, I receive the error no such file or directory. How am I able to find the maximum number of days a password can be use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check_output` expects the command as a list:

```
subprocess.check_output(['grep', 'PASS_MAX_DAYS', '/etc/login.defs'])
```

Alternative is to pass `shell=True`, taking into account the [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations)

```
subprocess.check_output('grep PASS_MAX_DAYS /etc/login.defs', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep PASS_MAX_DAYS /etc/login.defs` is being interpreted as a single executable, which can't be found. Use an array to pass an executable with arguments.

```
subprocess.check_output(['grep', 'PASS_MAX_DAYS', '/etc/login.defs'])
```

Answer (score 1):

the argument of the function check_output has to be a list, so just add split at the end of your command string

```
import subprocess 
pass_max = subprocess.check_output('grep PASS_MAX_DAYS /etc/login.defs'.split())
print(pass_max)
```

That should work

Answer (score 0):

try this -
[shell_output](https://github.com/vaddisrinivas/small_script)

By using the above you should be able to overcome all the challenges that otherwise appear with a subprocess module
Usage -

```
print(shell_output("your shell command here"))
```